# Remembering Anime/cartoon from around 10 years ago

Tags: ranma

Okay so I remember normal looking people.

Then a kid who was really weird looking, Like a completely different art style and drawn badly.

He went on adventures I think

I remember him chasing a bra. (But that scene could be mixed up with something else)

Other than that all I remember is that I watched all of it because I remember the seasons started over on tv. I watched it when I was around 6 and I am now 17.

I think it was cartoon network but I'm not sure or maybe fox kids this was in the Uk by the way.

Thanks in adanced

Comment: This probably isn't much of a match, but I suppose it is possible to mistake Happosai in Ranma 1/2 for a poorly drawn kid.

Comment: Yep, that's the one thank you.

Will wait to approve your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could potentially be a match for Ranma 1/2

It has a character named Happosi.  He's a step below "one of the main characters", so even though the show doesn't revolve around him, you'll see him often.

He's also not a child, He's actually really old, But It is possible to mistake him for a child because he's really short and he acts like one too.  He does look poorly drawn when compared with the rest of the characters.

This is what he looks like

[image]

Comment: Case closed, here sir take my burger I filled it with love